# Is there a way to add an add-on to Apple Subscriptions - flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter, in-app-purchase, payment

For example, on a Flutter application for iOS, we have different levels of 'premium'.
Premium 1 ($20) - no ads
Premium 2 ($30) - no ads and more content
Premium 3 ($40) - no ads and more content and better quality images

If the user was to upgrade from Premium 1 to Premium 2, is there a way to handle this that they don't pay the full $30 for everything, but rather they pay the $10 difference? And are billed $30 the next renewal period?
Thanks!

Comment: You put the subscriptions in a subscription group. If the user upgrades to a higher tier then Apple takes care of refunding the cheaper subscription and charges the user for the higher tier. https://www.revenuecat.com/blog/engineering/ios-subscription-groups-explained/